# retrieving test execution result : unit test

Tags: unit-testing, maven, testng

i'm new to testing:
I have to execute selenium tests and for that i'm using TestNG (because i need reports and log files),  so after the execution i will display the result of the execution faild or succeed, so how can i get the result of the test .

```
public class GoogleNavigationTest {
@Test
public  void testApp(){


    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
    // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

    // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
    // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
        }
    });

    // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

    //Close the browser
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

I'm using maven to run tests with `mvn test` command line .

Any hep will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing an application, you would be verifying some expected results.  For this, you need to add assertions to your testcases to assert that what you expect is the way your app is behaving.  TestNG has recently added the capabilities of [flexible](http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/) [asserts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/testng-users/Q5KGi30f0FE).

The report autogenerated by TestNG is index.html in your output folder, which can give you the execution details and logs(if you have logged any) and the failures if any.